# Searching keys with gpg results in key server failure

Tags: arch-linux, gpg, key-authentication

The following simple command is failing

```bsh
$  gpg --search-keys "hi"
gpg: error searching keyserver: Server indicated a failure
gpg: keyserver search failed: Server indicated a failure
```

Probably `hi` is not associated to a key, but still... shouldn't I get a *does not exist* error?

Therefore I think I'm misusing `gpg` command.

Oh, my version is `gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27`.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the "old" GnuPG (currently v1.4.23) works as expected:

```
$ /usr/bin/gpg --search-keys "hi"
gpg: searching for "hi" from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: key "hi" not found on keyserver
```

I can reproduce your issue with `gpg2` (2.2.27):

```
$ /usr/bin/gpg2 --search-keys "hi"
gpg: error searching keyserver: Server indicated a failure
gpg: keyserver search failed: Server indicated a failure
```

I can remediate the issue by explicitly declaring the keyserver to use:

```
$ /usr/bin/gpg2 --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --search-keys "hi"
gpg: data source: http://[2a03:4000:8:5c9:a86d:e5ff:fea9:7bc4]:11371
gpg: key "hi" not found on keyserver
gpg: keyserver search failed: Not found
```

It seems like gpg2 does not like the old keyserver option. From `man gpg2`:

> `--keyserver name`
> This option is deprecated - please use the --keyserver in ‘dirmngr.conf’ instead.

I'm not an expert on dirmngr and details about its conf file don't seem to be covered anywhere. I speculate it may be sufficient to add `keyserver <preferred-keyserver>` to `~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf` to permanently fix the gpg2 behaviour if you don't want to give the `--keyserver` option every time.

Comment: For some reason, when I use your command `/usr/bin/gpg2 --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --search-keys "hi"` I still get the same error as with `gpg --search-keys "hi"`.

Answer (score 1):

On my system, dirmngr from GnuPG uses DNS resolution through Tor by default.
For me, the following configurations of dirmngr works:

*~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf*

```
standard-resolver
no-use-tor
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Then, kill the process. It will be restarted automatically:

`$ pkill dirmngr`

Please be aware that this confguration could be less secure rather than the default.